# Is it correct to say that such constraint is called: emptiness integrity constraint?

Tags: constraint

I'm taking a database course, and I'm currently learning about integrity constraints. What happens is that in the teacher's material there is a constraint that is called: emptiness integrity constraint. This restriction basically informs if a certain field forces certain data to be inserted or not, in short, we are talking about NULL/NOT NULL.

However, I don't know if it is correct to say that the constraint name is the same. I'm afraid I'm learning something incorrect, and I don't want to take it with me, because I want the true knowledge, so if anyone can tell me whether it's correct to believe what they said or not, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It's more of a theoretical term, normally you would just say "NOT NULL constraint"

Comment: Something being NULL is not the same as being empty, so "emptiness integrity constraint" is incorrect.